# paypal form redirection inside form tags

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

i m learning paypal integration here...

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics

it says that html form shall have this one line

```
<FORM action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

my query is that since my form is this...

```
<form id="BuyForm" name="BuyForm" method="post" action="purchase.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

If i change action="purchase.php" to that provided by paypal i ll lose all my validation and php coding which i did on this page only "purchase.php". how can it work then??

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your existing page with action "purchase.php". Once user submits this form and you get what you need you can redirect user to a redirect page, on this page there will be a hidden form with action "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" and hidden fields containing values you need to pass to paypal. you need to display a redirect message on the screen and submit this form using javascript (Also add a submit button saying that "Click here if your not redirected").

Comment: Paypal gave mw this code for their buy now button... 

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SOME VALUE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

Comment: shall i use this code to show the buy now button given by paypal?? insode my main form tags.. but that will nullify the values of the actual submit button of my form "BuyForm"... how can i actually redirect it to as you said above??

Comment: Can you give brief of what your trying to achieve? Are you using the paypal buy now button or want to implement payment standard? https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf